# Multiple Plot + array function

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

please I have two problems in my script in Mathematica.

I have the following code (the part of it is):

```
varx := Table[x[i], {i, n} ];
vary := Table[y[i], {i, n} ];
varM := Table[M[i], {i, n} ];
var := Union[varx, vary, varM];
sol = NDSolve[eqns, var, {t, 0, 50}]
```

I would like to plot results for all M[i]. I know how to do it, but it is not such a clever idea:

```
    Plot[{{  Evaluate[M[2][t] /. sol]}, {  Evaluate[M[3][t] /. sol]}, {  
    Evaluate[M[4][t] /. sol]}, {  Evaluate[M[5][t] /. sol]}, {  
    Evaluate[M[6][t] /. sol]}, {  Evaluate[M[7][t] /. sol]}, {  
    Evaluate[M[8][t] /. sol]}, {  Evaluate[M[9][t] /. sol]}, {  
    Evaluate[M[10][t] /. sol]}, {  Evaluate[M[11][t] /. sol]}, {  
    Evaluate[M[12][t] /. sol]}, {  Evaluate[M[13][t] /. sol]}, {  
    Evaluate[M[14][t] /. sol]}}, {t, 0, 10}, 
  PlotLegends -> MaTeX /@ setM, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-1.05, 0.05}},
   AxesLabel -> MaTeX /@ {t, M}, BaseStyle -> texStyle];
```

Please can you help me how can I plot it more elegantly that have so many {Evaluate...} in the argument?

My second problem is very similar, but it is conderning x and y variables.
1. I would like to assign the result value of x and y to a new variable. Is here a possibility how to do it at once? Now I am doing this:

```
X[1][t_] := x[1][t] /. sol
Y[1][t_] := y[1][t] /. sol
X[2][t_] := x[2][t] /. sol
Y[2][t_] := y[2][t] /. sol
X[3][t_] := x[3][t] /. sol
Y[3][t_] := y[3][t] /. sol
```

... etc.

I know that it is something with array functions, but unfortunately I am not so familiar with them.

Thank you very much for your help and Merry Christmas to everybody.

Comment: `Evaluate[M[#][t] /. sol] & /@ Range[2, 14]`? You can use a similar approach for the second part of your question.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. But if I want to use the similar approach for the second part (and do it as `Evaluate[X[#][t_] := x[#][t] /. sol & /@ Range[1, 14]]` it does not make anything, the output for the input X[1][0] is only X[1][0]... Is here a possibility how to asign these variables?

Comment: Try `Evaluate[(X[#][t_] := x[#][t] /. sol) & /@ Range[1, 14]]`.

Comment: Thank you, that works.